# AXIS and Spring password in properties with CallbackHandler

Tags: spring, apache, apache-axis, ws-security

I have a problem with Apache Axis and Spring. I've got this class as CallBackHandler in WS-Security for setting a pasword:

```
public class PasswordCallbackHandler implements CallbackHandler {
    @Override
    public void handle(Callback[] callbacks) throws IOException, UnsupportedCallbackException {
        for (int i = 0; i < callbacks.length; i++) {
            WSPasswordCallback pwcb = (WSPasswordCallback)callbacks[i];
            pwcb.setPassword("mysecretpassword");
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to set the password in a .properties. I can't use a classpath resource, my properties are outside the classpath. This class (`PasswordCallbackHandler`) is outside from my Spring Context, so I can't use `@Value`tag.

Which is the best way to put this password in a properties file? I've tried to use `raedicomws.crypto.properties` and `raedicomws_client_config.wsdd`,but I couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 2):

you can use System.setProperty("key","value"); method where you are going to get/read property from your .yml/.properties file with @Value annotation.
Then you can get the set data with System.getProperty("key"); method on your Axis method.
I have done the same way for CXF webservice (The same method for security) and it has worked.